# Can there be a minus value of microtesla?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am currently making an application with a magnetometer sensor, when I launched it I saw that it displays a minus value.

Answer (score 2):

Why not? Magnetic fields are directional. The sign is giving you information about the field orientation. This should be in the spec sheet of the magnetometer.